# Generate random between 0 - 9 but not 6

Tags: javascript, random

What is the simplest way to generate a random number between 0 - 9 (inclusive both) excluding 6 in Javascript?

Comment: CarbonicAcid, I love to do it, and see it being done; when someone do "explain what to do" in steppy way!

Comment: @IsmetAlkan well, this is something so simple that not making any effort is not acceptable...

Comment: When I said love, I meant love.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is your one line solution :(

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9][Math.floor(Math.random()*9)]
```

Comment: It's does not have 6 so it's must be 9 @H2CO3

Comment: @imana97 It does not have 6 so total of 9 element in the array. NOT 10

Answer (score 12):

Generate a random number between 0 and 8 and then add 1 if it's >=6

Comment: @Sawarnik Does my solution fit your needs? (Though I don't see what's wrong with this one).

Comment: @Sawarnik This algorithm does gives all number equally likely to appear. `Generate a random number between 0 and 8` gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` equally likely, and `add 1 if >=6` gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]` equally likely.

Comment: for(var rnd=0; rnd != 6; rnd++) {
rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)
}
I was thinking something like this, please point out if there's anything wrong. I'll try your method now.

Comment: @Sawarnik are you aware what the parts of a for loop do? You totally messed that up.

Comment: writeln((i = Math.floor(Math.random()*9))>=6?i+1:i); //One line, they're all equally likely :)

Comment: for(var rnd, k=0; rnd != 6; k++) { rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) } this thing?

Comment: `x = rand between 0 to 3` has 25% to give 0, 25% to give 1, 25% to give 2 and 25% to give 3. `add 1 if x >= 1`  afterwards keep probabilities of getting each number unchanged, but add 1 if the number >= 1 i.e. 25% to give 0, 25% to give 1, 25% to give 3 and 25% to give 4

Comment: @Sawarnik it can be done, but what you wrote does not do what you want. Probably `var r; for (r = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10); r != 6; r = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 10));` is better.

Answer (score 7):

The naïve approach:

```
var r;
do {
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
} while (r == 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to be lazy here and take @H2CO3's answer to be working without trying it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function generate(var UNWANTED) {
    var r;
    do {
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    } while (r == UNWANTED);
    return r;
}

function GENERATE_RANDOM_FROM_0_TO_10_BUT_NOT_6_OR_SOMETHING_ELSE_(var NOT_GOOD){
    return generate(NOT_GOOD)     <== One line solution.
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var n = (n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)) == 6 ? 9 : n;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var numbers = "012345789";
var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length);
var randomnumber = parseInt(numbers.substring(rnum,rnum+1));
```

Comment: This produces a string. The final expression should be prefixed with `+` to coerce to a number.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var rr=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
result=(rr==6)?1:rr;
```

**Edit:**
 
The probability of 1 is not likely other, so I made it to recursive if it generate 6.

```
function notSix() {
  var rr=(Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
  return (rr==6)?notSix():rr;
}

notSix()
```

Correcting the first example:
generating between 0-8 first and if outputs 6 converting to 9;

```
var rr=(Math.floor(Math.random()*9));
result=(rr==6)?9:rr;
```

Comment: This algorithm would generate 1 more likely than others. In particular, this has 20% to give 1 and other only 10%, because both 1 and 6 maps to 1.

Comment: @vusan and also if it originally generated 1.