# Two random numbers

Tags: javascript, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate random between 0 - 9 but not 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017124/generate-random-between-0-9-but-not-6)

```
var ifanse=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1; 

var ifanse2=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1
```

These are 2 random numbers. Sometimes they come equal, but is there any way if `ifanse` come equal to `ifanse2`, it will regenerate a random between 3 - 1 but exclusive of `ifanse2`. Or is there any way to avoid equaling at first place?

Comment: So you do not want them to be completely random?

Comment: Really? Haven't you learnt ***absolutely nothing*** from the question you asked yesterday? You can use the same do-while loop...

Comment: i want them to be random, but they should not be equal.

Comment: @H2CO3 probably you can say that. but some of the methods in the previous answer didnt seem to fit the variable and random demands. i will try the do-while now, i hadnt tested it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop until you pick a different number:

```
var ifanse=Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1; 
var ifanse2=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
while (ifanse2 == ifanse)
{
   ifanse2=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
}
```

Comment: sometimes ifanse generates 4. i want it to be restricted within 3.

Comment: then replace the `*4` with a `*3` ..

Answer (score 2):

You could for example write a generic function which gives you an array of random numbers

- Filling and Array with the Numbers of your range *Which will eliminate duplicate numbers*
- shuffling the Array
- return an Array of the lenght, with the count of random Numbers you want

---

```
  function genRand(min, max, cnt) {
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = min, j = 0; i <= max; j++, i++)
      arr[j] = i
      arr.sort(function () {
          return Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) - 1)
      });

      return arr.splice(0, cnt)
  }

console.log(genRand(0, 3, 2)) // e.g [0,3]
```

Then you could just store them in your var, or access them directly from `rands`

```
var rands = genRand(0,3,2);
var ifanse = rands[0]
var ifanse2 = rands[1]
```

You would never get 2 equal Numbers with this and you can generate more then 2 different rands if you ever need to.

Heres a [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/avovox/1/edit)